How to Change a Recommended Policy for All Users in MS Edge?
Currently, in our organization we set the Edge homepage as a Recommended policy (allowing users to change if they wish).
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\Recommended]
HomepageLocation = "www.example.com"

We are now looking at changing this homepage URL. However, changing this key will only affect new users since it is currently set as Recommended. Existing users will be unaffected by a change here.
How can we change the homepage URL for both new and existing users while still allowing users to change it if they desire?
We only want to change it for existing users if the user hasn't changed it from the default, as specified in the key above.

Existing users if the user hasn't changed it from the default will get the new recommended HomepageLocation. Why do you think Existing users will be unaffected by a change?

Since you change the policy, it will get updated on every computer, including ones where users have set another homepage. If a user navigates to the homepage settings at edge://settings/startHomeNTP
and did not set a custom value before, the new value will be pre-set there.
Users who have set a custom value can see the recommended one at edge://policy/
Where they are guided to by a hint at the top of the settings page via an intermediate link to edge://management/.

I am not sure this answer actually answers the author's question. I think they are looking to set it without user involvement. That certainly would be my expectation if I were to have this question, although I would simply delete the user's Edge profile to force the update personally.

It is without user involvement. Navigating there in the settings is only meant to show that the new policy has taken effect. Instead the user can simply click the homepage button an will be taken to the new homepage of the new policy.
